# Get the selected item of dropdown list from code behind

Tags: asp.net

How to get the selected value of a dropdownlist in code behind?

In my aspx page I have a dropdown list

Using Jquery, I'm adding items

```
var city = $("#city").val();
if (city.toString() != "") {
    var citySelect = $('#cityName');
    citySelect.append($('<option></option>').val('0').html('-Select City-'));
    for (i = 0; i < City.response_list.length; i++) {
        citySelect.append($('<option></option>').val(City.response_list[i].id_city + " - " + City.response_list[i].label).html(City.response_list[i].id_city + " - " + City.response_list[i].label));
    }
}
```

In code behind when I try to get the selected value, 
 I'm getting "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How to get the selected value?

Comment: Are you binding your list on page_load?

Comment: i believe you are accessing the control you've added via jQuery in your code behind. In that case the control is not a server side control which will not be seen in your code behind.

Comment: @hallie : OP is getting Runtime error not Compile time

Comment: @rose: can you also show the html snippet and the code where you hit the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your **Select input** which you add some **options** with JQuery to it, it is a **Client side object and in no circumstances you can have access to it using code behind**

To access this object you have to add to property to your select input

**ID** and **runat=server** thsese to property let you access your object from the code behind, you final select should be something like this

```
<select id="select1" runat="server">
    <option value="val1">dfgbfbff</option>
</select>
```

then in your code behind you can check its values with checking the **select1**